# How I can access the fields without translation through an instance of TranslatableModel?

Tags: python, django, imagefield, django-hvad

I need the name of the project (field project, no translation) for build the path of upload_to directory in ImageField. But i get this error:

AttributeError at /admin/api/stage/add/
'StageTranslation' object has no attribute 'project'

```
def stage_name_path(instance, filename):
    # get error at instance.project
    return '/'.join(filter(None, (instance.project, 'stages', filename)))

class Stage(TranslatableModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        'Short name',
        max_length=50
    )
    text = models.CharField(
        'Text',
        max_length=120
    )
    translations = TranslatedFields(
            image=models.ImageField(
            'Image (i18n)',
            upload_to=stage_name_path
        ),
    )

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='stages')
```

Through the instance I can access the fields with translation (image) but I can not access the fields name, text or project... the ones who really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:`instance.master.project`. The `StageTranslation` has a `ForeignKey` field `master` is a reference to `Sage`.

Comment: I try it and run perfectly. Thanks for the reply.